# What does this SaveAs syntax have or does not have that prevents execution?

Tags: vba, excel

Have developed code with exact examples on this website, yet will not run and stops at `SaveAs...` line. Can anyone spot my mistake?

**I get this error:**

[image]

Yet the path `C:\dads\Downloads\` does exist,  the file is not in use by another program, and it has a different name. What am I missing?

```
Option Explicit

Sub PickupRoutes_Click()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Lrow As Integer, NewFile As String

    Lrow = 7
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 33), Cells(Lrow, 38))

    '~~> Copy the range from the current Workbook
    Rng.Select
    Rng.Copy

    'Establish a new Workbook and paste range
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

    '~~> Paste rng in Cell A1.
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    '~~>. Save the file
    NewFile = "C:\dads\Downloads\" & "PlanMyRoute_" & _
        Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFile, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    MsgBox "PlanMyRoute file has been saved "

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot `Users` in the path: `NewFile = "C:\Users\dads\Downloads\" & ...`

Comment: The path shown in the screenshot doesn't seem to match the code you posted?

Comment: Try `NewFile = environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\PlanMyRoute_" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy\.\x\l\s\m")`. If you are not *Dads* there may be a permissions issue.

Comment: Screenshot and code doesn't match. on the screenshot seems the `.xlsx` misssing

Comment: duuh...C:\Users\.....was missing.  Thanks, staring at the screen too long. @PortlandRunner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file path doesn't exist the error message will tack on what looks like a memory address which is why the error message and the code don't match.

It appears you are missing the `Users` directory in the path.

Change to:

```
NewFile = "C:\Users\dads\Downloads\" & "PlanMyRoute_" & _
    Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
```